# Spring Cloud Task with 2 data sources fails even when TaskConfigurer is manually configured

Tags: spring-cloud

Good day,

I have a Spring Cloud application that makes use of 2 data sources and the documentation indicates that I should manually create the TaskConfigurer to use the correct data source which I have done as follows:-

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource primaryDataSource;

    @Bean
    public TaskConfigurer taskConfigurer() {
        return new DefaultTaskConfigurer(primaryDataSource);
    }
}
```

The TaskConfigurer and associated repository is configured correctly by Spring however when the SimpleTaskConfiguration is invoked by Spring to complete the configuration the validation always fails on the fact that there are 2 data sources regardless of there being just the one task configurer.

Kind regards,

Mark P Ashworth

[Debug screenshot showing that verifyEnvironment() is failing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp7zF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the @Primary annotation in addition to define the TaskConfigurer to make auto configuration work. Like this:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
  ...
}
```